Raymarching compute shader error in Unity VR
I am trying to apply a raymarching shader to my Unity VR project.
It is supposed to apply a shader to particles that represent a fluid using Smooth Particle Hydrodynamics.
However, I am running into this error:
Compute shader (Raymarching): Property (_DepthTexture) at kernel index (0) is not set
UnityEngine.StackTraceUtility:ExtractStackTrace ()
FluidRayMarching:OnRenderImage (UnityEngine.RenderTexture,UnityEngine.RenderTexture) (at Assets/Scripts/FluidRayMarching.cs:90)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

And the Unity VR scene fails to start beyond the Unity Logo at the beginning.
In the Unity Game window, all I get is a black screen.

I am new to shaders and am still trying to learn but I am not making good sense of it.
I appreciate any help with this.
Thank you.
This is the script that I have, called FluidRayMarching.cs:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FluidRayMarching : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ComputeShader raymarching;
    public Camera cam;
    
    List<ComputeBuffer> buffersToDispose = new List<ComputeBuffer>();
    
    public SPH sph;

    RenderTexture target;

    [Header("Params")]
    public float viewRadius;
    public float blendStrength;
    public Color waterColor;

    public Color ambientLight;

    public Light lightSource;


    void InitRenderTexture () {
        if (target == null || target.width != cam.pixelWidth || target.height != cam.pixelHeight) {
            if (target != null) {
                target.Release ();
            }
            
            cam.depthTextureMode = DepthTextureMode.Depth;

            target = new RenderTexture (cam.pixelWidth, cam.pixelHeight, 0, RenderTextureFormat.ARGBFloat, RenderTextureReadWrite.Linear);
            target.enableRandomWrite = true;
            target.Create ();
        }
    }


    private bool render = false;

    public ComputeBuffer _particlesBuffer;

    private void SpawnParticlesInBox()
    {
       _particlesBuffer = new ComputeBuffer(1, 44);
       _particlesBuffer.SetData(new Particle[] {
        new Particle {
        position = new Vector3(0,0,0)
       }});

    }

    public void Begin() {
        // SpawnParticlesInBox();
        InitRenderTexture();
        raymarching.SetBuffer(0,"particles",sph._particlesBuffer);
        raymarching.SetInt("numParticles",sph.particles.Length);
        raymarching.SetFloat("particleRadius", viewRadius);
        raymarching.SetFloat("blendStrength", blendStrength);
        raymarching.SetVector("waterColor", waterColor);
        raymarching.SetVector("_AmbientLight", ambientLight);
        raymarching.SetTextureFromGlobal(0, "_DepthTexture", "_CameraDepthTexture");
        render = true;
    }


    void OnRenderImage (RenderTexture source, RenderTexture destination) {
        
        // InitRenderTexture();

        if (!render) {
            Begin();
        }

        if (render) {

            raymarching.SetVector ("_Light", lightSource.transform.forward);

            raymarching.SetTexture (0, "Source", source);
            raymarching.SetTexture (0, "Destination", target);
            raymarching.SetVector("_CameraPos", cam.transform.position);
            raymarching.SetMatrix ("_CameraToWorld", cam.cameraToWorldMatrix);
            raymarching.SetMatrix ("_CameraInverseProjection", cam.projectionMatrix.inverse);

            int threadGroupsX = Mathf.CeilToInt (cam.pixelWidth / 8.0f);
            int threadGroupsY = Mathf.CeilToInt (cam.pixelHeight / 8.0f);

            raymarching.Dispatch (0, threadGroupsX, threadGroupsY, 1);

            Graphics.Blit (target, destination);
        }
    }

}


And this is the shader, called Raymarching.compute:
#pragma kernel CSMain

Texture2D<float4> Source;
RWTexture2D<float4> Destination;
Texture2D<float4> _DepthTexture;

float4x4 _CameraToWorld;
float4x4 _CameraInverseProjection;

static const float maxDst = 80;
static const float epsilon = 0.001f;
static const float shadowBias = epsilon * 50;

struct Particle
{
    float pressure;
    float density;
    float3 currentForce;
    float3 velocity;
    float3 position;
};

StructuredBuffer<Particle> particles;
int numParticles;
float particleRadius;
float blendStrength;
float3 waterColor;
float3 _Light;
float3 _AmbientLight;
float3 _CameraPos;

struct Ray {
    float3 origin;
    float3 direction;
};

float SphereDistance(float3 eye, float3 centre, float radius) {
    return distance(eye, centre) - radius;
}

Ray CreateRay(float3 origin, float3 direction) {
    Ray ray;
    ray.origin = origin;
    ray.direction = direction;
    return ray;
}

Ray CreateCameraRay(float2 uv) {
    float3 origin = mul(_CameraToWorld, float4(0,0,0,1)).xyz;
    float3 direction = mul(_CameraInverseProjection, float4(uv,0,1)).xyz;
    direction = mul(_CameraToWorld, float4(direction,0)).xyz;
    direction = normalize(direction);
    return CreateRay(origin,direction);
}

// polynomial smooth min (k = 0.1);
// from https://www.iquilezles.org/www/articles/smin/smin.htm
float4 Blend( float a, float b, float3 colA, float3 colB, float k )
{
    float h = clamp( 0.5+0.5*(b-a)/k, 0.0, 1.0 );
    float blendDst = lerp( b, a, h ) - k*h*(1.0-h);
    float3 blendCol = lerp(colB,colA,h);
    return float4(blendCol, blendDst);
}

float4 Combine(float dstA, float dstB, float3 colourA, float3 colourB) {
    float dst = dstA;
    float3 colour = colourA;
    float4 blend = Blend(dstA,dstB,colourA,colourB, blendStrength);
    dst = blend.w;
    colour = blend.xyz;
    return float4(colour,dst);
}

float GetShapeDistance(Particle particle, float3 eye) {
   
    return SphereDistance(eye, particle.position, particleRadius);
    return maxDst;
}


float4 SceneInfo(float3 eye) {
    float globalDst = maxDst;
    float3 globalColour = waterColor;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < numParticles; i ++) {
        Particle particle = particles[i];

        float localDst = GetShapeDistance(particle,eye);
        float3 localColour = waterColor;


        float4 globalCombined = Combine(globalDst, localDst, globalColour, localColour);
        globalColour = globalCombined.xyz;
        globalDst = globalCombined.w;        
    }

    return float4(globalColour, globalDst);
}

float3 EstimateNormal(float3 p) {
    float x = SceneInfo(float3(p.x+epsilon,p.y,p.z)).w - SceneInfo(float3(p.x-epsilon,p.y,p.z)).w;
    float y = SceneInfo(float3(p.x,p.y+epsilon,p.z)).w - SceneInfo(float3(p.x,p.y-epsilon,p.z)).w;
    float z = SceneInfo(float3(p.x,p.y,p.z+epsilon)).w - SceneInfo(float3(p.x,p.y,p.z-epsilon)).w;
    return normalize(float3(x,y,z));
}

float CalculateShadow(Ray ray, float dstToShadePoint) {
    float rayDst = 0;
    int marchSteps = 0;
    float shadowIntensity = .2;
    float brightness = 1;

    while (rayDst < dstToShadePoint) {
        marchSteps ++;
        float4 sceneInfo = SceneInfo(ray.origin);
        float dst = sceneInfo.w;
        
        if (dst <= epsilon) {
            return shadowIntensity;
        }

        brightness = min(brightness,dst*200);

        ray.origin += ray.direction * dst;
        rayDst += dst;
    }
    return shadowIntensity + (1-shadowIntensity) * brightness;
}

float LinearEyeDepth( float rawdepth )
{
    float _NearClip = 0.3;
    float FarClip = 1000;
    float x, y, z, w;
    #if SHADER_API_GLES3 // insted of UNITY_REVERSED_Z
        x = -1.0 + _NearClip/ FarClip;
        y = 1;
        z = x / _NearClip;
        w = 1 / _NearClip;
    #else
        x = 1.0 - _NearClip/ FarClip;
        y = _NearClip / FarClip;
        z = x / _NearClip;
        w = y / _NearClip;
    #endif
    
    return 1.0 / (z * rawdepth + w);
}

[numthreads(8,8,1)]
void CSMain (uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    uint width,height;
    Destination.GetDimensions(width, height);

    Destination[id.xy] = Source[id.xy];

    float2 uv = id.xy / float2(width,height) * 2 - 1;
    float rayDst = 0;

    Ray ray = CreateCameraRay(uv);
    int marchSteps = 0;

    float depth = LinearEyeDepth(_DepthTexture[id.xy]);

    

    while (rayDst < maxDst) {
        marchSteps ++;
        float4 sceneInfo = SceneInfo(ray.origin);
        float dst = sceneInfo.w;

        if (rayDst >= depth) {
            Destination[id.xy] = Source[id.xy];
            break;
        }
        
        if (dst <= epsilon) {
            float3 pointOnSurface = ray.origin + ray.direction * dst;
            float3 normal = EstimateNormal(pointOnSurface - ray.direction * epsilon);
            float3 lightDir = -_Light;
            float lighting = saturate(saturate(dot(normal,lightDir))) ;

            float3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, normal);
            float spec = pow(max(dot(ray.direction, reflectDir), 0.0), 32);
            float3 specular = 0.7 * spec * float3(1,1,1);

            float3 col = sceneInfo.xyz;

            float3 t1 = cross(normal, float3(0,0,1));
            float3 t2 = cross(normal, float3(0,1,0));
            float3 tangent = float3(0,0,0);
            if (length(t1) > length(t2)) {
                tangent = normalize(t1);
            }
            else {
                tangent = normalize(t2);
            }

            float3x3 tangentMatrix = float3x3(tangent,cross(tangent, normal),normal);

            float3 viewDir = normalize(pointOnSurface-_CameraPos);

            float3 refracted = mul(tangentMatrix, refract(viewDir, normal,1));
            

            Destination[id.xy] = float4(lerp(col, Source[id.xy+(refracted.xy)], 0.8) * (specular + _AmbientLight + lighting * 0.01),1);
           

            break;
        }

        ray.origin += ray.direction * dst;
        rayDst += dst;
    }
}


Your approach seems fine and assigning the texture in OnRenderImage sounds reasonable. I don't know exactly why but for me using SetTextureFromGlobal(0, "_DepthTexture", "_CameraDepthTexture"); in the first update loop solved it.

Thank you for your comment. I will try your suggestion.
